# How to call a javascript function from within a Laravel blade template to add route param

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

Good Afternoon, I have a blade template in a Laravel 10 app, and I need to pass some value from a table row to a route as a parameter. the $invoices array is the JSON response from Wafeq accounting REST API service.

Here is the route.

```
Route::get('invoices/{id}/wafeq', [InvoiceController::class, 'showWafeq'])->name('invoice.show-wafeq');
```

The function called by the route is:

```
public function showWafeq(WafeqService $wafeq, string $id)
{
    try {
        $invoice = $wafeq->getInvoice($id);
        dd($invoice, $wafeq->invoiceDataSanitation($invoice));
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        echo $th->getMessage();
        //throw $th;
    }
  } 
}
```

And the blade templates form and javascript functions are as follows:

1--Blade Template Form:

```
  <form class="needs-validation" novalidate method="GET" action="{{ route('invoice.show-wafeq', ['id' => getInvoiceId()]) }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="text-center pt-5">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg add-spinner" type="submit">Add Selected Invoices</button>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <div class="p-2">
                            @if (count($errors) > 0)
                            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
                            </div>
                            @endif


                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">

                
                                    <table class="table table-hover table-responsive table-striped table-bordered" id="laravel_datatable" style="overflow: auto; " >
                                        <thead class="table-dark">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th><input/ type="checkbox"></th>
                                                <th>Invoice No</th>
                                                <th>Invoice Id</th>
                                                <th>Customer</th>
                                                <th>Amount</th>
                                                <th>Due date</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            @foreach ($invoices['results'] as $item)
                                            <tr>
                                                
                                                <td> <input type="radio" name="invoice_id" value="{{ $item['id'] }}"></td>
                                                <td> {{ $item['invoice_number'] }}</td>
                                                <td > {{ $item['id'] }}</td>
                                                <td> {{ $item['contact'] }}</td>
                                                <td > {{ $item['amount'] }}</td>
                                                <td> {{ $item['invoice_due_date'] }}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>



                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </form>
```

2-- Javascript function

```
  <script>
           function getInvoiceId(){
           return (document.getElementById('invoice_id').innerText) ; 
           }
  </script>
```

Thanks a lot in advance.and have a nice day.

Comment: `{{ route('invoice.show-wafeq', ['id' => getInvoiceId()]) }}` - That will not work. Anything inside of `{{ }}` is PHP code, and you can't call a JS function in PHP. PHP is server-side and runs _long_ before JS (client-side) has even constructed the function. If you do something like `{{ route('invoice.show-wafeq', ['id' => ':invoiceId']) }}`, then you can replace the text `:invoiceId` from the generated Route via JS with whatever you want when you need to submit this form. That's my typical approach to using JS variables in a Laravel Route; define a placeholder, replace with JS value.